# How to keep showing selected option from drop down list?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a drop down list where I select options

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="styled-select">
<select name="seasons" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value="">Select a Season</option>
<option value="1">2002/2003</option>
<option value="2">2003/2004</option>
<option value="3">2004/2005</option>
<option value="4">2005/2006</option>
<option value="5">2006/2007</option>
<option value="6">2007/2008</option>
<option value="7">2008/2009</option>
<option value="8">2009/2010</option>
<option value="9">2010/2011</option>
<option value="10">2011/2012</option>
<option value="11">2012/2013</option>
<option value="12">2013/2014</option>
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
```

You can see the list here [footystat](http://footystat.co.uk/index_2.php)

I am using the following PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['seasons'])){ $seasonette = $_POST['seasons']; } 

if(isset($_POST['year'])){ $yearette = $_POST['year']; }

if(isset($_POST['comp'])){ $competitionette = $_POST['comp']; }

if(isset($_POST['which'])){ $whichette = $_POST['which']; }
```

When I select something from the list, I want selected item in the list to continue showing. At the moment when I select (for example) 2013/2014, it will show the results but the drop down menu goes back to its original state instead of showing 2013/2014.

Comment: is this a static list or are you populating the list using php?

Comment: You are submitting the form onchange, so the DOM contents get reloaded. So when rendering the page again you need to manually set the value to the drop downs.

Comment: entire page is reloading with new content.

Comment: I am using PHP to populate the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Option value selected when it gets posted value, like this,

```
<option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['seasons']) && $_POST['seasons'] == '1'){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>2002/2003</option>
```

Set value like this for each option

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "selected" property to the option , just like you set a value !

```
<option value="8" selected>2009/2010</option>
```

Use a if statement in PHP to determine which one should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the page refreshes.

On page load check if there is post variable than match the value with each option's HTML and write selected attribute.

Comment: this is not the answer. you should comment

Answer (score 0):

The shorter way is

```
<option value="1" <?php echo $_POST['seasons']==1?"selected":""; ?>2002/2003</option>
```